# How to create fixed toolbar with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I have tried many times on Chrome extension files to change the CSS of looks of the my new plugin.

The problem is when I tried to scroll down the page some headers with fixed positions are getting hidden behind my extension (websites likes Youtube, Outlook ,Gmail) 
I've tried to create a translation to the body element with CSS3 and it didn't work as well.

```
.html{
  transform: translateY('50px');
}
```

I even tried to lower down some fixed positioned elements with JQuery but it messed up with the page and some of the sites just crashed!

```
var fixed = $('*').filter(function()
        {
            return $(this).css('position').toLowerCase() == "fixed";


        });

    for(i=0; i<fixed.length; i++)
    {
        var marginTop = window.getComputedStyle(fixed[i]).getPropertyValue('margin-top');

        fixed[i].style.marginTop = parseInt(marginTop)+"152px";


var marginBottom = window.getComputedStyle(fixed[i]).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom');
       fixed[i].style.bottom = parseInt(marginBottom) + "152px";

  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do?  It *sounds* like you want a fixed header on all web pages that doesn't conflict with existing websites, is that right?

Comment: That's tricky... the problem is different pages achieve these results in different ways, and handling this on each page could be different.  I'm not sure how one would achieve a one size fits all solution...